# Windows 8 SDK Content and Search functionality

Tags: windows-8

Does the Windows 8 SDK contain information such as conceptual information and help for keywords that can give an insight into Windows 8 for developers?

Is it similar in functionality to the SharePoint 2010 SDK where we can search for a particular topic and it enables Help for the topic and shows results rated by importance?

Comment: Did you think to use Google before asking this, you are expected to do some research before asking questions here on SU.

Comment: yes, i did but one thing i need to know that is there any detailed description available as it is there in SharePoint 2010 SDK.Like searching a articular topic enables help and gives more options..

Comment: Why is this not in your question?, you can edit your question to be more specific, and you will likely get upvotes for a good question, which this has the potential to be one.

Comment: i say in answer that Integrated DirectX SDK The DirectX SDK is now part of the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the Windows 8 SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx).

**However,** there is one major difference from previous releases of the Windows SDK:

> "The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. You must install a compiler and build environment separately."

You will need to download and install [Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express) if you need a compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The download page is here: [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx)

Use this SDK to:

> 1. write Windows Store apps (only on Windows 8)
> 2. using web technologies (such as HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript)
> 3. deploy desktop applications
> 4. .NET Framework 4.5 SDK
> 5. **Samples** to [download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/) and test
> 6. Integrated DirectX SDK The DirectX SDK is now part of the Windows SDK.

You can download samples and change them as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx)